# How to specify a custom route name for razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

Is there a way to specify a custom route name for a razor page?

For controllers and actions, it's possible by, for example, using the `RouteAttribute` like this:

```cs
[Route("my-custom")]
public class MyCustomController
{
    [Route("my-index")]
    public IActionResult MyIndex() => View();
}
```

Is there any similar approach regarding razor pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible by customizing the routing template of the `@page` directive within the cshtml file.
In the `MyIndexPage.cshtml` razor page, for example;

```
@page '/my-index'
@model MyIndexPageModel

...
```

Without forgetting the forward slash (`/`) at the beginning.